# How to Deserialize a very Simple RestSharp JSON Object?

Tags: json, object, deserialization, restsharp

Forgive what surely has to be a dumb question, but I'm just starting out with C# using JSON.

I have this class:

```
public class DBCount
{
    public string Count { get; set; }
}
```

I create an instance:

`public DBCount dbCount;`

My web service is returning this:

> [{"Count":"234"}]

This code throws an invalid cast when it tries to deserialize the response:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.../")
var request = new RestRequest ("demo/jsondbcount.php",Method.GET);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

var response = client.Execute (request);
RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserialCount = new JsonDeserializer();
dbCount =  deserialCount.Deserialize<DBCount> (response);
```

Here's the invalid cast error:

> "Cannot cast from source type to destination type"

If anyone can point me to a basic, simple example of using `RestSharp` to deserialize a simple object I'd be very grateful.  I've searched everywhere for a basic code sample.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to add the serializable attribute to your class?

Answer (score 1):

You may have figured this out already but the problem is `[]`.  `[{"Count":"234"}]` is an **array** of size 1 that contains a single object with the field `Count`.

If you want your server to return an object that will deserialize to a `DBCount` then return `{"Count":"234"}` without the `[]`.

If you want your code to correctly deserialize `[{"Count":"234"}]` then you need to indicate that it's deserializing a collection like so:

```
deserialCount.Deserialize<List<DBCount>>(response);
```